# Angular 9 Typescript - How to pass the textbox entered value to a directive's input string

Tags: angular, typescript, user-input

I need to pass the value entered in the textbox to another directive's input variable, without using ngModel.
**How to achieve this** ? Below is the code.

```
HTML : 

<input type="text" placeholder='Type here' /> **The textbox to get the user's input value** 
<searchDirective [searchText]=''></searchDirective> **Need to pass the textbox's value to this [searchText] input variable**


*In searchDirective.component.ts :*

export class searchDirective implements OnInit {

@Input() searchText: string;

ngOnInit(): void {}

@HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick($event) {
 **On this click event need to get the textbox's input value that the user entered** 
}

}
```

Comment: Can you also mention why do you not want to bind the input value to a variable and pass it?

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to use ngModel and template reference as answered by LogicBlower then try this

```
<input type="text" placeholder='Type here' id="search"/>
<searchDirective [searchText]='inputValue' (click)="doSearch()"></searchDirective>
```

in a component to which above html template belongs create field inputValue and  write doSearch method like

```
doSearch() {
    this.inputValue = document.getElementById("search").value
}
```

You can perform operation on input value in ngOnChanges lifecycle hook of your searchDirective

```
ngOnChanges() {
    // searchText value is accessible here
}
```

Comment: my god, not, it's not an Angular way. If you want at least use a template reference variable but not document.getElementBy

Comment: I know. But he does not want ngModel which can solve his problem instantly. And someone else has posted template reference way @Eliseo

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

Create a ref with **#inputRef** (any name you prefer) in the input and pass that value in searchDirective (both are in same HTML) **inputRef.value** as input has a value property

HTML :

```
<input type="text" placeholder='Type here'  #inputRef /> **The textbox to get the user's input value and #inputRef will help in accessing value in template** 
<searchDirective [searchText]='inputRef.value'></searchDirective>
```